# improve ghostscript to tiff conversion quality

Tags: ghostscript, tiff, equality, file-conversion

I need to convert some `.pdf` file to fax format (`tiff 200x 200 dpi`)
at the moment I'm using `GS 9.27` with the following arguments:

```
-r214 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dFIXEDRESOLUTION
```

But the sound quality i not good, how do I improve it or ajust the contrast/brightness?

You can find original document [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1drV9rxR4zgQEdr2HZBkFygcSlzrTe96T), how it was converted by GS and how it was converted by adobe.

Comment: You are rendering to a 1-bit per pixel (monochrome) output file, there is no 'contrast' or 'brightness' (or indeed, sound). You need to be a lto more explicit about the problem you see, to me the Ghostscript output is supoerior, I see less thinning of the glyphs for example. However, you are clearly not rendering these the same way; the Acrobat output is 8.64x11.675 inches, while the Ghostscript output is 8.075x11.696 inches (the original file has media 8.26x11.69. Seems to me the Ghostscirpt output is rather nearer in size. Of course, you have told Ghostscript to use a fixed media size of A4.

Comment: The original PDF file doesn't include Helvetica, but it does use it, so you are going to get a substitute font which will also affect the appearance. Finall, you have not (apparently) changed the halftone screen (the file does not contain a halftone) so you are probably getting an inappropriate halftone used.

Comment: hello
thank you for your comments,I?m not familiary with Gs, and I'm using a workflow that other have implemented years ago. So, in GS conversion, I don't know how add other fonts or use right halftone .

for my opinion, font converted by GS was too 'grey'. this output should be sent by fax and shuold be most black possible.

Comment: The 'font' (I assume you mean text here) can't possibly be 'grey' because its a monochrome output, black and white. Shades of gray, or colour, are emulated by using a halftone screen, an effect not unlike dithering. Which text are you referring to ? There is a lot of text on the first page (and there are 5 pages) in at least 3 different fonts. Some is in pure black, some in red, and some in a shade of gray.